# Как вывести определённый размер header image?

Tags: wordpress

Всем привет. У меня есть шапка, у которой есть фоновое изображение. Оно выводится бэкграундом. `<header class="header_image" style="background-image: url(<?php header_image(); ?>);">`. Функция header_image() выводит оригинал изображения. Как мне сделать так, чтобы выводилось большое изображение 1024х613?
Можете предложить изменить функцию.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: Картинка]

Comment: @KAGGDesign
https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_header_image
_Если нужно вывести УРЛ на экран, а не получить его для обработки, используйте функцию header_image()._ У меня всё работает подобным образом.

Comment: А почему нельзя просто залить картинку нужного размера?

Comment: @SeVlad, потому, что другой пользователь может это не делать, и сайт из-за этого будет загружаться дольше.

Comment: Какой-то "другой" пользователь (не админ) может менять картинку в шапке? 0_О О, ужас........ А "загружаться дольше" будет НЕ из-за физ размеров картинки, а из-за объёма файла. Кто не умеет оптимизировать графику - тех вообще нельзя допускать к сайтостроению.

Comment: @SeVlad, это шаблон на продажу. Themeforest и другое.

Comment: А.. ну тогда я понимаю откуда там всякое УГ за деньги продаётся.. шаблон.. Начни что ли изучать ВП. Непосредственно  с терминологии. А еще посмотри как это сделано в нормальных темах - там есть и показ размеров и возможность обрезки до нужных размеров непосредственно в ВП.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

К сожалению, эта функция не работает с id изображения, так что стандартные средства вывода картинки меньшего размера не помогут. Можно сделать так:

```
$url = get_header_image();
$url = str_replace( '.jpg', '-1024x613.jpg', $url );
echo esc_url( $url);
```

Comment: Спасибо! Только не get_header_img, а get_header_image.

Comment: Точно. Исправил опечатку.

Comment: Прикинь, это, оказывается для "шаблона" на продажу на платных помойках :)

Comment: @SeVlad моему костыльному коду из ответа там самое место))

Comment: @SeVlad а если серьёзно, то я не понимаю, почему header_image так по-уродски сделана, не через id

Comment: Я особо не вникал, но поверхностно глянул - не увидел с наскоку  и потому согласен с тобой, что тут наверняка есть недоработка. Но и решать как ТС - это тоже ппц. (а ты говоришь что на платных помойках продаются нормальные темы :) ) Может и попадаются, но мне такие не встречались). К вопросу ТС - мало того, что он не понимает зачем это нужно, но и то, что в нормальных темах есть обрезка картинки прямо при заливке.

Comment: Ты насчёт рувп слака  передумал? ;) https://ruwp.slack.com

Comment: @SeVlad я потыкался и не понял, как подключиться без инвайта, сейчас еще раз попробую